# Throwing WebapplicationException from one webapp and getting UniformInterfaceException on other

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, jersey

I see a weird issue. I have two webapps. One for the rest webservice that we exposed using Jersey. Another has the JSF Front End implementation which calls above webservice to fetch the details. We are using Tomcat as a container.

The issue that i am facing is when i call a rest webservice, i throw WebApplicationException like this

```
catch (CustomExceptions e) {
    ResponseBuilder response = new ResponseBuilderImpl();
    response.status(500);
    response.entity(e.getStackTrace());
    throw new WebApplicationException(e, response.build()); 
}
```

And on the other hand on FE webapps, i do the following:

```
try {
    r.get(MyClass.class);
    return "SUCCESS";
} catch (WebApplicationException wae) {
    return "FAILURE";
} catch (UniformInterfaceException wae) {
    return "FAILURE";
}
```

Here in the catch block i was expecting the WebApplicationException but its throwing UniformInterfaceException which is weird. Also if it throws UniformInterfaceException, It does not maintain the stacktrace. Even the response that i passed in from rest call is lost. Can somebody help me how can i get the original stacktrace from the rest call?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

As specified in both the [user guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e673) and the [api documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html), a UniformInterfaceException is the expected result when you attempt to retrieve a specific entity by type but receive a non-200-series response. The WebApplicationException is a convenience exception for your use on the server side to embed custom responses in an exception.

Nothing is "lost". Keep in mind you're making an HTTP request here. If you want to inspect the status code and response yourself, use

```
ClientResponse response = r.get(ClientResponse.class);
if (response.getStatus() == <expected status code>) [
    response.getEntity(MyClass.class);
    // do happy path stuff
} else {
    // bad stuff here
}
```

Alternately, assume everything will go well, and only check the response on exceptions:

```
try {
    r.get(MyClass.class);
} catch (UniformInterfaceException e) {
    ClientResponse response = e.getResponse();
    // do whatever with the raw response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue before. I think it's because Jersey `WebResource.get` method throws only `UniformInterfaceException` which is not in the inheritance hierarchy of `WebApplicationExcpetion`. What I did is to abandon Jersey client side api but use plain `ApacheHttpClient`. Will be able to get the right stacktrace in the httpResponse contents.

Hope this helps.

---

Thanks, Ryan. I tried your solution. Very nice.